# Set to 0 the Component-count of gsutil composed objects (rateLimitExceeded Error)

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

While copying some log files (created via gsutil compose command):

```
gsutil -m cp -R gs://mybucket/PROD/ gs://mybucket/TEST/
```

we are hitting lots of errors like this one:

```
"errors":[  
    {  
        "domain":"usageLimits",
        "reason":"rateLimitExceeded",
        "message":"The total number of compose requests for this bucket's project exceeds the rate limit. Please reduce the rate of compose requests."
    }
],
"code":429,
```

Doing a gsutil stat over those objects I can see that their Component-Count is 972 and such.

We have tried to go the short way:

```
gsutil setmeta -h "Component-Count:0" gs://mybucket/PROD/composite.log
```

but we hit a:

```
CommandException: Invalid or disallowed header (component-count).
Only these fields (plus x-goog-meta-* fields) can be set or unset:
```

Actually, the copying proccess is fully executed so it is only that it is quite annoying to see all those errors.

Does anyone know how to set the component-count to 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely ignore those errors. As you you have noticed, `gsutil cp` command completes its job.

If you want to get rid of those errors, you might want to try this workaround to set to 0 the [`Component-Count`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects#_Count) header of the composite object, and basically "un-compose" the objects. To do so, you can dump it to the wire and back again to Cloud Storage.

A simple way to do this is by using the ["daisy-chain"](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options) mode (-D option) from the cp command:

```
gsutil cp -D gs://mybucket/PROD/composite.log gs://mybucket/PROD/notcompositeanymore.log
```

It even works fine with gsutil -m (multi-threaded) and cp -R (recursive) options!

If you are concerned about increasing speed and lowering the costs of this process, I'd suggest you do it from within a Compute Engine VM, preferably in a zone close to your bucket.

Happy coding!

Comment: FYI, you can use `gsutil cp -D gs://mybucket/PROD/composite.log gs://mybucket/PROD/notcompositeanymore.log`. This is exactly what `-D` was designed for - no need to chain.

Comment: Might also want to link to [the docs on component count](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects#_Count).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the right way to do it. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer necessary. GCS no longer enforces a rate limit on copy operations involving composite objects.